# Scrolling and Image sizing Issues?

Tags: c4

Downloaded the testScrollView file and can't get it to work right.

https://github.com/C4Code

It seems everything is in order for the most part, no major errors pop up or anything, but when I try to run it on the simulator it pops up in the bottom right saying "destination buffer size too large (15360 x 768); cannot be larger than 4096 x 4096", and the debugging window pops up as well.

Is there some sort of special command that needs to be added?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue last week, apparently the simulator doesn't like the large image. However, this example works just fine on a device. The reason is that there is a large 15360x768 image that the example breaks down into 256x256 tiles.

Try compiling for an iPad if you have access to one.